# Sufficient condition for every subspace to be compact.

Tags: general-topology

Every  open subspace of a  topological space is compact then prove that all the subspaces are compact.

I know little bit about compact spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A$ be any subspace and let $(U_i)$ be an open cover. Then $U=\cup_i U_i$ is an open set covered by $(U_i)$ so (by hypothesis)  a finite number of $U_i$ cover $U$. This finite collection covers $A$.